# Fitting sin curve using python

Tags: python, curve-fitting

[image]

I am having two list:

```
# on x-axis:
# list1:
[70.434654, 37.147266, 8.5787086, 161.40877, -27.31284, 80.429482, -81.918106, 52.320129, 64.064552, -156.40771, 12.37026, 15.599689, 166.40984, 134.93636, 142.55002, -38.073524, -38.073524, 123.88509, -82.447571, 97.934402, 106.28793]

# on y-axis:
# list2:
[86683.961, -40564.863, 50274.41, 80570.828, 63628.465, -87284.016, 30571.402, -79985.648, -69387.891, 175398.62, -132196.5, -64803.133, -269664.06, 36493.316, 22769.121, 25648.252, 25648.252, 53444.855, 684814.69, 82679.977, 103244.58]
```

I need to fit a sine curve `a+bsine(2*3.14*list1+c)` in the data points obtained by plotting list1(on x-axis) against(on-y-axis) using python.

I am not able to get any good result.Can anyone help me with a suitable code,explanation...

Thanks!

this is my graph after plotting the list1(on x-axis) and list2(on y-axis)

Comment: My eyes hurt. Give us some code and format your text in question a little.

Comment: i have two lists list1 and list2...how can i fit a sin curve according to the data points obtained by plotting list1 against list2

Comment: Do you have any python experience? This is a pretty broad question. There are a lots of ways of graphing data in python

Comment: I have started learning python 6 months before....i have given the graph of my plot ...provide me a code that will fit the sin curve ..

Comment: Ah ok. It was hard to understand what you needed help with the way the question was originally written. I don't know how the method or code for this off the top of my head, but perhaps someone else can help you.

Comment: Have a look at this [curve fitting example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) using `scipy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you used lmfit setting up and running your fit would look like this:

```
xdeg  = [70.434654, 37.147266, 8.5787086, 161.40877, -27.31284, 80.429482, -81.918106, 52.320129, 64.064552, -156.40771, 12.37026, 15.599689, 166.40984, 134.93636, 142.55002, -38.073524, -38.073524, 123.88509, -82.447571, 97.934402, 106.28793]

y = [86683.961, -40564.863, 50274.41, 80570.828, 63628.465, -87284.016, 30571.402, -79985.648, -69387.891, 175398.62, -132196.5, -64803.133, -269664.06, 36493.316, 22769.121, 25648.252, 25648.252, 53444.855, 684814.69, 82679.977, 103244.58]

import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sinefunction(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * np.sin(x*np.pi/180.0 + c)

smodel = Model(sinefunction)
result = smodel.fit(y, x=xdeg, a=0, b=30000, c=0)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xdeg, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(xdeg, result.best_fit, '*', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That is assuming your X data is in degrees, and that you really intended to convert that to radians (as numpy's sin() function requires).

But that just addresses the mechanics of how to do the fit (and I'll leave the display of results up to you - it seems like you may need the practice).

The fit result is terrible, because these data are not sinusoidal.  They are also not well ordered, which isn't a problem for doing the fit, but does make it harder to see what is going on.

Comment: I wanted to see your code working but it says " No module named lmfit"..

Comment: Thanks it helped me to some extent.If have any suggestions to get better result or to make the data in order ..list1 is actually longitude and list2 is corresponding electron density

Comment: I see that your example calls smodel.fit() with values for initial parameter estimates. In this specific example, what method did you use to determine the initial parameter values in your example code?

Comment: @JamesPhillips  Hi James, I looked at the graph and guessed that the scale of b was around 10,000.

Comment: @Abhaskumar  try `pip install lmfit`.

Comment: @M Newville.....output:[[Variables]]
    a:   2.2037e+05 +/- 3.99e+04 (18.11%) (init= 0)
    b:  -63480.3315 +/- 5.93e+04 (93.36%) (init= 70000)
    c:  -0.29123185 +/- 0.858969 (294.94%) (init= 0)   .What those range signifies for a,b,c and how can i store the amplitude i.e value of b.Help me this.I need to store the value of amplitide i.e b.

Comment: @Abhaskumar Please read docs.  `result.params['b'].value` holds the value of parameter `b`.

Comment: @ M Newville ..thanks .....one question more i think value of b is amplitute of the sin function we are using...but why it is negative ..can i just take |b| as the amplitude value...what does that negative value signify?

Comment: This may be due to the sin() function returning a negative value during the fit, so the multiplier "b" was fitted to a negative value to make the "b * sin()" part of the equation yield a positive value. With other data, the sin() might have returned positive values, so in my opinion the negative value of "b" itself is not likely to have any special significance here.